# Hive TBLPROPERTIES from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm not seeing anything in the documentation, but is there a way to query the Hive `TBLPROPERTIES` for a table from Spark using a `HiveContext` or Hive-backed `DataFrame`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the `tblproperties`

Comment: @Virureddy No, just query them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot access the `HiveMetastoreClient` that Spark uses inside its `HiveSession`.

But, you can just instantiate another one -- hopefully the CLASSPATH is OK and contains both the Hive JARs *and* the directories containing Hadoop/Hive config files, and you don't have Kerberos authentication (or you benefit from the implicit Hadoop UGI of the Spark driver, that handles Kerberos automagically); so it's just a matter of `new HiveMetaStoreClient(new HiveConf())`

Then `.getTable(...).getParameters()` should get you the TBLPROPERTIES you want, in a Java `Map`.

https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but I'll accept this if just going via the Hive client completely independently of Spark is the only solution.

Comment: If you are brave enough to read the Spark source code thoroughly, maybe you will find a hack; but IMHO, the `SQLContext`/`HiveContext` part is not the most readable...